# Objeto de javascript vacía cuando accedes a el a traves de las keys del padre en un bucle

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando acceder al atributo de un objeto con una key autogenerada, por lo que tengo que iterar por sus keys y acceder al objeto padre con la key como indice. El problema viene cuando hago un console.log del indice, que se recoge bien, pero cuando accedo al atributo del objeto me devuelve un objeto vacío (en lugar de undefined).

```
      console.log(detailArray)
      detailArray.forEach((detail) => {
        for(var i in detail) {
          if (detail.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
              console.log(i, detail[i])
          }
        }
      })
```

Estos son los valores devueltos en el primer console.log

```
[
  {
    "2gC28U711o": {
      "number": "654324232",
      "operator": {
        "id": 0
      },
      "paymentModality": "contract",
      "action": "portability"
    }
  }
]
```

Y estos los del console log en el bucle

```
 2gC28U711o  {}
```

¿Qué se me escapa?

**UPDATE**
Este código se encuentra en una función a la que se llama en cada success de varias llamadas asíncronas, teniendo un contador para verificar que se trata de la última. Fuera de esta función, esta iteración funciona correctamente.

Gracias por adelantado

Comment: Hola Juan Pablo, esto parece una pregunta interesante pero probando el código compartido [no he podido reproducir el problema](https://jsfiddle.net/j70jcv8k/) (¿quizás tenga que ver con el alcance de las variables? ¿o algo que afecte en otro punto?). Sería ideal si pudieras crear un [mcve] en la propia pregunta para que veamos el problema en sí (puedes añadir un snippet a la pregunta dándole al icono `<>` del editor).

Comment: Ya de paso, te doy la bienvenida al sitio. Completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre Stack Overflow en español (y así ganar una nueva medalla). Saludos.

Comment: El problema radica en que poco después en otra función se esta iterando de la misma manera por el mismo array y si puede acceder, pero sin embargo en esta función no.

Comment: Ok. ¿Cómo se obtienen los valores de `detailArray`? ¿Los traes a través de AJAX? Quizás podría ser un problema por ejecutar el código antes de que el valor esté ahí. Deberías añadir algo más de código y un [mcve] si es posible para que podamos ver el problema (al menos la parte en la que falla y la parte en la que funciona).

Comment: Se trata de una propiedad de la clase donde se encuentra esta función, tiene los valores rellenos antes de entrar. Se llama a esta función a través de varias llamadas asincronas, pero solo se entra en este bucle cuando se han terminado todas mediante un contador, y de hecho, el console log del detailArray esta dentro de la función, por lo que tiene valores cuando esta dentro.

Comment: Tal y como lo describes, lo más probable es que se esté llamando al bucle antes de que alguna de esas llamadas asíncronas haya terminado. Pero para poder saber exactamente qué es lo que falla, tendrías que compartir más código, porque la parte que compartes es correcta y funciona sin problemas (de forma síncrona, como te puse en un ejemplo en [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j70jcv8k/)). Hace falta ver más contexto para identificar el problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tras estar investigando, he encontrado el error.
Todo viene de que console.log no es fiable para saber los valores de una variable.
He hecho en el bucle un console.log(JSON.stringify(detailArray)) y salia vacio como en el console log inicial, lo que significa que en ese punto detailArray efectivamente no tenía datos, sino que mostraba los datos del futuro.

Tras reordenar el código ya funciona.

Este [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284663/console-log-shows-the-changed-value-of-a-variable-before-the-value-actually-ch/11284675#11284675) ha sido útil para encontrar qué podía ser.